# OnPageScrolled Scale FAB

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, floating-action-button

How can I improve this code? I'd like to show a FAB only if fragment with position 0 is displayed, hiding it with scale effect when user swipe to other view pager fragments. The value:

```
(1 - positionOffset)
```

never reach exactly 0, so I've add setScale(0). This way before complete disappearing the FAB needs to wait that the new position (e.g. 1) is set. I'd like to have a more fluid behaviour, can you help me?

```
viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
                if (fab != null && position == 0) {
                    fab.setScaleX(1 - positionOffset);
                    fab.setScaleY(1 - positionOffset);
                } else {
                    fab.setScaleX(0);
                    fab.setScaleX(0);
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: You should use animation for "fluid behavior". I recommend having a look at toggle() method here https://github.com/makovkastar/FloatingActionButton/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/melnykov/fab/FloatingActionButton.java which is part of this lib: https://github.com/makovkastar/FloatingActionButton and replacing the translation animation with scale animation.